# Capturing an event when user stops scrolling

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, dom-events

I am attempting to capture an event when a user stops scrolling, I've read the [JavaScript Event API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) but am still a bit confused on where to begin.

**Question:** How can I capture the event when the user stops scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timeout:

```
var timer = null;

function done() {
  console.log('done scrolling');
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }

    timer = setTimeout(done, 150);
}, false);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fz79gmts/3/**

Comment: Haha exactly what I was going to put, I modified your answer just for more clarity rather than posting another answer and being non-constructive...